# ubuntu script to retain only latest file of each folders and delete everything else

Tags: ubuntu, bash, backup, shell-script, find

We have a script which takes hourly backups and stores it inside a folder created as today's date.

```
#CRONJOB TO BACKUP DB HOURLY

DAY=$(/bin/date +%d%m%Y)
TIME=$(/bin/date +%H%M%S)

if [ ! -d /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/$DAY ]; then
  sudo mkdir /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/$DAY
fi
sudo chmod -R 755 //home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/$DAY
cd /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/$DAY/

mysqldump -u root -p'password' current > current_$TIME.sql

zip current_$TIME.zip current_$TIME.sql > /dev/null 2>&1

sudo rm current_$TIME.sql
```

So, there will be 24 files inside the folder **20072018** and names will be like **current_000001.zip**

Now we are running out of space, so decided to keep only one backup per day and delete everything else.

I tried the following script, which deletes everyhting but 23rd hour backup.

```
sudo find /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/* -type f \( -name "*_00*.zip" -o -name "*_01*.zip" -o -name "*_02*.zip" -o -name "*_03*.zip" -o -name "*_04*.zip" -o -name "*_05*.zip" -o -name "*_06*.zip" -o -name "*_07*.zip" -o -name "*_08*.zip" -o -name "*_09*.zip" -o -name "*_10*.zip" -o -name "*_11*.zip" -o -name "*_12*.zip" -o -name "*_13*.zip" -o -name "*_14*.zip" -o -name "*_15*.zip" -o -name "*_16*.zip" -o -name "*_17*.zip" -o -name "*_18*.zip" -o -name "*_19*.zip" -o -name "*_20*.zip" -o -name "*_21*.zip" -o -name "*_22*.zip" \) -mtime +30 -delete
```

But problem is for some of the days 23rd backup is not available because the server was shutdown. 
How can I modify the above script so that it checks for **LATEST BACKUP FILE of each date**  and retain only that file and delete everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
ls /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/$DAY/*_[012][0-9]*.zip | head -n -1 | \
       while read -r f; do rm "$f"; done
```

This finds all the archive files in the directory sorted lexicographically, then uses `head` to list all but the last (`-n -1`) and removes the listed files in a `while` loop.

I suggest you put `echo` before `rm` initially, in order to see what commands will be executed before using live.

Comment: Thanks But problem is inside cron_database_hourly directory there will be many folders named after respective date. ex: 20072018, 21072018 and I want to delete files from all of these directories, and I need to apply thses rules for files that are 30 days old only.

Comment: You can't use the same technique on the directories, since the temporal order is not the same as the lexicographic order. Unless your file system supports file birth dates, you cannot reliably use `find -newerXY` either. If you changed the directory format to `DAY=$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d)`, then temporal order becomes the same as lexicographic. Otherwise, you will need to use a series of three sorts on the columns containing the year, month and day respectively. It's too long for a comment, but if you ask a new question, I'll try and answer it.

Comment: I have created a seperate question: 
 https://superuser.com/questions/1342472/script-to-remove-all-but-retain-one-latest-backup-file-of-all-sub-directories

Comment: Your new question has removed the requirement for the files to be 30 days old, which makes the problem a lot simpler. Is this no longer a restriction? it certainly makes the problem a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
ls datedir | head -n -1 | xargs rm
```

(untested, so don't subject precious data to this without testing)