# Script to remove all, BUT retain one latest backup file of all sub-directories

Tags: bash, shell-script

The following script works for single folder, but I want to iterate through all subdirectories.

```
ls /home/user/Desktop/cron_database_hourly/*/*_[012][0-9]*.zip | head -n -1 | \
   while read -r f; do rm "$f"; done
```

Comment: That does not seem like valid syntax — are you missing an `ls -l` in the beginning or similar?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have updated the question

Comment: I suspect that the ls  should be ls -t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably get away with something like  (untested) -

```
for each in `find -type d /home/usr/Desktop/cron_database/hourly`
do
   ls -t $each/_[012][0-9]*.zip | head -n -1 | \ while read -r f; 
       do 
           rm "$f" 
      done
done
```

the "for each" will loop will find a list of all directories, and adding a "-t" to ls will cause it to sort in date order - with most recent first.

Comment: As I read it, this will remove all but the _oldest_. Don't you need `ls -rt`? Or use `tail -n +2`?